# How can count duplicate array value in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with duplicate values.

I want  print all items but also for duplicate value, I want print a number too.

Like this:

```
$arr = array('sara','jorj','sara','sara','jorj','eli','ana')

foreach($arr as $name)
{
   echo $name;
}
```

How can  print this result:

```
sara
jorj
sara-2
sara-3
jorj-2
eli
ana
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get an array of all elements which are before the current element of the iteration, e.g.

```
iteration value   |  sliced array
-----------------------------------
     sara         |       []
     jorj         |     [sara]
```

Then I use this array with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), to only keep the values with are equal to the current iteration value, so I can tell how many of the same values are in the array before the current value.

Now I simply have to [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) how many there are and if there are more than 1 we also print it in the output.

Code:

```
$arr = array('sara','jorj','sara','sara','jorj','eli','ana');

foreach($arr as $key => $name) {
    $count = count(array_filter(array_slice($arr, 0, $key), function($v)use($name){
       return $v == $name;
    })) + 1;

   echo $name . ($count > 1 ? " - $count" : "") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
sara
jorj
sara - 2
sara - 3
jorj - 2
eli
ana
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Im little bit late to this answer, but heres my attempt

```
$arr = array('sara','jorj','sara','sara','jorj','eli','ana');
$tmp = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!isset($tmp[$value]) ) {
        // if $value is not found in tmp array
        // initialize the value in tmp array and set to 1
        $tmp[$value] = 1;
        echo $value;
    }
    else {
        // found the value in tmp array
        // add 1 to the value in tmp array
        // output its current total count of this value
        $tmp[$value] += 1;
        echo "$value-", $tmp[$value]; 
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

output:

```
sara
jorj
sara-2
sara-3
jorj-2
eli
ana
```

This actually has the same output of `array_count_values`, but broken into pieces of how it forms...I think